# Is there an event on a DataGridView that fires when multiple rows are deleted?

Tags: .net, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` in my application where the user is allowed to select multiple rows. The user can also delete them by pressing `Del`. Now, the `DataGridView` represents entries from a database and I want to show a confirmation dialog box before actually deleting the rows.

The catch is: I only found a `UserDeletingRow` event that fires on each separate row to be deleted, so when the user selects 100 rows, I get 100 events. Displaying the confirmation there would then mean that the user has to confirm 100 single deletions.

The only thing I can think of now is to prevent deleting in the `UserDeletingRow` event as per `e.Cancel = true` and set up a separate one that fires when the user presses the `Del` key and figures out what is selected then.

Did I just not hit the correct keywords when searching for this issue, or is there really no event in .net that fires when deleting multiple rows?

Comment: Just an idea. Suppose you select 3 rows and than set e.Cancel = true in the first time you enter UserDeletingRow event, will the event still fire for the other 2 rows ? If not, you could copy DataGridView1.SelectedRows in that event, set e.Cancel = true and than call another method that handles the copy of the selectedrows.

Comment: Yes, the event still fires for the other two. The event fires on every single deleted row, and unfortunately, when the handling method is called, I do not know if there are other events left in the pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can intercept the pressing of the Del key, and handle it yourself. When you set up the DataGridView, you need to assign an event handler for key presses:

```
grid.KeyDown += new Forms.KeyEventHandler(grid_KeyDown);
```

The handler can get confirmation from the user:

```
private void grid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Delete)
        return;

    e.Handled = true; // Very important to prevent the Del key being handled elsewhere!

    // Ask user to confirm here; return if they back down...

    DeleteSelectedRecords(); // this is your own method
}
```